# Textfield onChange not works with react and MobX

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mobx, mobx-react

I have a textField which are be controlled by a MobX store, but if I enter something to the textfield only on letter will change. Here my code. There is my mistake?

I made my component as observer and my Store is makeAutoObservable inside the constructor.

```
class SettingsStore {
  constructor() {
    makeAutoObservable(this)

    makePersistable(this, {
      name: 'SampleStore',
      properties: ['roadmapDescription'],
      storage: window.localStorage
    })
  }

  async onChangeRoadmapTitle(name: string): Promise<void> {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('input', name)
      this.roadmapDescription.title = name
      console.log(
        'this.roadmapDescription.title',
        this.roadmapDescription.title
      )
    }, 50)
  }
}
```

Here is my React Code

```
const SettingsGeneral: React.FC<ISettingsGeneral> = observer(({ onSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Form<{ title: string; description: string; dataSource: string }>
        onSubmit={(data) => onSubmit(data)}
      >
        {({ formProps = 'test', submitting }) => (
          <form {...formProps}>
            <FormSection>
              <Field
                aria-required={true}
                name='title'
                label='Name of the Roadmap'
                isRequired
              >
                {({ fieldProps }) => (
                  <Fragment>
                    <TextField
                      testId='roadmap-title-text-field'
                      autoComplete='off'
                      {...fieldProps}
                      className='w-48'
                      onChange={async (
                        e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
                      ) =>
                        await settingsStore.onChangeRoadmapTitle(e.target.value)
                      }
                      value={settingsStore.roadmapDescription.title}
                    />
                  </Fragment>
                )}
              </Field>
          </form>
        )}
      </Form>
    </div>
  )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake was I use value and not defaultVaule

Correct solution is:

```js
<Fragment>
  <TextField
    testId='roadmap-title-text-field'
    autoComplete='off'
    {...fieldProps}
    className='w-48'
    onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
      settingsStore.onChangeRoadmapTitle(e.target.value)
    }
    defaultValue={settingsStore.roadmapDescription.title}
  />
</Fragment>
```